# Image in VueJS component is not loading

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I got a parent component which sends a data object to the children component like this:

`<child object-data=" url: 'url here', title: 'Title'"></child>`

Then on my children component, I get this object data by doing:

```
<script>
    export default {
        props: [
            'objectData'
        ]
    }
</script>
```

Now, for some reason, I can use title without any problem like this `{{ objectData.title }}` and shows up.

But when it comes to the URL inside an img tag it's not rendering the image.

I attempted doing the following:

`<img :src="objectData.url"/>` <--- not rendering

`<img v-bind:src="objectData.url"/>` <--- not rendering

`<img v-bind:src="require(objectData.url)"/>` <-- throws a warning error because it's not a path but an object I guess.

`<img v-bind:src="{objectData.url}"/>` <--- throws an error

`<img v-bind:src="{{objectData.url}}"/>` <--- throws an error

When I check on the dom element, it doesn't even contain a src attribute afterwards.

If I write down the URL without an object, it works.

`<img v-bind:src="src/assets/images/icon.png"/>`

But I want my URL to come from a parent component.

Any ideas on how to solve this? I added the url-loader on my webpack file:

```
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
                loader: 'url-loader'
            }
```

I also attempted returning `objectData.url` from a computed/methods fuction:

```
computed: {
     getImageUrl: function() {
           return objectData.url;
     }
}
```

And then use it like `:src=“getImageUrl”` or `:src=“{{getImageUrl}}”` and I wasn’t lucky either.

Comment: Yes i faced the same issue before, and i didn't search a solution, but when i use url like `https://picsum.photos/500/300?image=5` it works fine

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim oh i have to check but yes, although my images will be stored for instance in my cdn, so that works as an external url... but there has to be a way to make this work for testing purposes haha

Comment: yes i'm agree with you and i have opened that project to find a solution using images stored in assets folder

Comment: When you examine the element on the rendered page, what is its `src` set to? Is it correct?

Comment: @RoyJ src attribute is completely gone.

Comment: Have you tried returning the image value from a computed instead?

Comment: @craig_h Yes i attempted that too. Forgot to add it, not only by computed: {} but also via methods: {}

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I faced the same issue and i fixed it by using `require` function  :

in the parent component `App.vue` :

```
<carousel-posts :posts="posts" />

export default {
 name: "app",
data() {
  return {
   posts: [
     {
      img: require("./assets/logo.png"),
      title: "Title 1",
      subTitle: "Sub Title 1",
      body:"lorem ipsum ..."
    }
    ...
    ]
    };
   }
  ...
 }
```

in the child component i loop through the `posts` and bind the image `src` as follows :

```
    <div class="card-body" v-for="(post,idx) in posts" >
      <img class="card-img" :src="post.img" />
         ...
     </div>

        <script>
           export default {
            props: ["posts"],
           ...
```

So in your case you should have something like :

```
     <child :object-data="objectData"></child>

        ...
     data(){ 
          return{
            dataObject:{
              url: require('./assets/someimg.png'), 
              title: 'Title'
             }
            }
          }
```

Update :

my project tree :

```
   src
   |_assets
   |   |_logo.png
   |_components
   |   |_CarouselPosts.vue
   |_App.vue
```

Comment: i will try it out in a couple minutes whenever i get home! thanks for the answer.

Comment: you're welcome, it works for me i hope that could work for you

Comment: I'm getting a: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'src/assets/images/image.png' in 'somepath'. Seems that the require('') is not resolving the path to my image. Any idea?

Comment: if the parent component is located in the same level of  `assets` folder in the project structure you should use `./assets/images/image.png`

Comment: I tried without the require('') and the image renders. Also, the image path doesn't seem to work if i use './assets' or '../assets' even though components and assets folder are in the same level. But when i add 'src/assets' it works... i don't want to have 'src' in the path :/

Comment: it works for me, i updated my answer by adding my project tree

Comment: Have you tried `'~/assets/images/image.png'`, `'~assets/images/image.png'` or `'@/assets/images/image.png'`?

Comment: @Rixcy i had tried that before according to the [vue cli doc](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#relative-path-imports) and that didn't work, the solution which i had provided works fine for me

Comment: @msqar please edit your question with new attempts and issues

Comment: It's okay, i can continue working from here, at least i can open a pic, although, having 'src' in the URL is a bad choice, right? but it's for now, the real images will come from a CDN url outside my project. I guess i'm okay by now! thanks for your help.

Comment: you're welcome and thanks to you because you call my attention to that

Comment: Common practice would be to `import` assets up top as variables rather than `require()` them.

Answer (score 3):

Two alternatives:

1. Static links that vue resolves. But they're src-based and don't work with webpack / file-loader:

```
<img :src="'../assets/filename.png'"/>
```

2. Works with webpack. Note the ".default" at the end:

```
<img :src="require('../assets/filename.png').default"/>
```

Documentation relevant effective Nov 2019:
https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/1612