# Vue js. Images from list not displaying properly

Tags: javascript, html, image, vue.js

I am trying to display all the images from a list in Vue js using v-for. Instead of images i am getting some icons visible on the screenshot below.

I can display the images one by with `<img class="carni" src="@/assets/Carnivores/acro.png" />` but when i am using v-for its not working. Also when i am inspecting the elements with devtools the code for every image is the same as i would display them one by one. Does anyone know what is the issue here?

[image: Text]

[HTML]

```
    <template>
      <div class="legacy">
        <br />
        <h1>The Isle Legacy Calculator</h1>
        <br /><br />
        <div class="row">
          <div class="column" style="background-color: #ffb3b3">
            <h2>Carnivores</h2>
            <p>Drag and drop below..</p>
            <img
              class="carni"
              v-for="carni in carniArray"
              :src="carni.src"
              :key="carni.id"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="column" style="background-color: #80ffbf">
            <h2>Herbivores</h2>
            <p>Drag and drop below..</p>
            <img
              class="herbi"
              v-for="herbi in herbiArray"
              :src="herbi.src"
              :key="herbi.id"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div>Matchup</div>
        <br /><br />
        <div class="row">
          <div class="column" style="background-color: #ffb3b3">
            <h2>Attacker</h2>
            <p>Some text..</p>
          </div>
          <div class="column" style="background-color: #80ffbf">
            <h2>Defender</h2>
            <p>Some text..</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br /><br />
        <button class="btn btn-indigo outline" @click="calculate">Calculate</button>
      </div>
    </template>
```

[Javascript]

```
    script>     
    export default {
      components: {},
      data() {
        return {
          carniArray: [
            { id: 'acro', src: '@/assets/Carnivores/acro.png' },
            { id: 'albert', src: '@/assets/Carnivores/albert.png' },
            { id: 'allo', src: '@/assets/Carnivores/allo.png' },
            { id: 'austro', src: '@/assets/Carnivores/austro.png' },
            { id: 'bary', src: '@/assets/Carnivores/bary.png' },
            { id: 'carno', src: '@/assets/Carnivores/carno.png' },
            { id: 'cerato', src: '@/assets/Carnivores/cerato.png' },
            { id: 'dilo', src: '@/assets/Carnivores/dilo.png' },
            { id: 'giga', src: '@/assets/Carnivores/giga.png' },
            { id: 'herrera', src: '@/assets/Carnivores/herrera.png' },
            { id: 'rex', src: '@/assets/Carnivores/rex.png' },
            { id: 'sgiga', src: '@/assets/Carnivores/sgiga.png' },
            { id: 'spino', src: '@/assets/Carnivores/spino.png' },
            { id: 'srex', src: '@/assets/Carnivores/srex.png' },
            { id: 'sucho', src: '@/assets/Carnivores/sucho.png' },
            { id: 'utah', src: '@/assets/Carnivores/utah.png' },
          ],
          herbiArray: [
            { id: 1, src: '@/assets/Herbivores/anky.png' },
            { id: 2, src: '@/assets/Herbivores/cama.png' },
            { id: 3, src: '@/assets/Herbivores/dibble.png' },
            { id: 4, src: '@/assets/Herbivores/dryo.png' },
            { id: 5, src: '@/assets/Herbivores/galli.png' },
            { id: 6, src: '@/assets/Herbivores/maia.png' },
            { id: 7, src: '@/assets/Herbivores/pachy.png' },
            { id: 8, src: '@/assets/Herbivores/para.png' },
            { id: 9, src: '@/assets/Herbivores/shant.png' },
            { id: 10, src: '@/assets/Herbivores/stego.png' },
            { id: 11, src: '@/assets/Herbivores/strike.png' },
            { id: 12, src: '@/assets/Herbivores/theri.png' },
            { id: 13, src: '@/assets/Herbivores/trike.png' },
          ],
        }
      },
      methods: {
        calculate() {
          alert('Calculating')
        },
      },
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: are you using vue cli or vite? and which vue version are you using?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim vue cli with vue 2.6.14

Comment: please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53683406/8172857