# Vue JS v-bind doesn't load images

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to use a `v-bind` element inside a for loop in Vue-js.

The `v-bind` should load an image for each element of a list.

Here's my code:

```
            <v-row v-for="skill in skillTech" :key="skill.title">
              <v-col cols="4" align-self="center">
              <img v-bind:src="skill.logo" width="30"/>
                <span class="body-1 font-weight-light ml-4">
                  {{ skill.title }}
                </span>
```

and the list:

```
<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    skillTech: [
      { title: "HTML5", rating: 4, logo: "https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/732/732212.png" },
      { title: "CSS3", rating: 4, logo: "../assets/html.svg" },
      { title: "JavaScript", rating: 4, logo: "../assets/html.svg" },
      { title: "Vue.js", rating: 3, logo: "../assets/html.svg" },
    ],
```

Thing is, the first element `HTML5` loads, but the others don't.

Here's what I get:

[image]

Here's the versions I'm using :

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@mdi/font": "^5.3.45",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "firebase": "^7.15.2",
    "roboto-fontface": "*",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-parallaxy": "^1.1.1",
    "vue-typed-js": "^0.1.2",
    "vuetify": "^2.2.11"
  },
```

Any ideas how to solve that ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53682725/8172857

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `require`-ing the assets.

Modify your `skillTech` array like this:

```
 skillTech: [
  { title: "HTML5", rating: 4, logo: "https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/732/732212.png" },
  { title: "CSS3", rating: 4, logo: require("../assets/html.svg") },
  { title: "JavaScript", rating: 4, logo: require("../assets/html.svg") },
  { title: "Vue.js", rating: 3, logo: require("../assets/html.svg") },
]
```

Comment: That works !! Thank you ! But why ? Do you have a link to some documentation ? I tried previously the `require` on the html as suggested on other posts but it didn't work.

Comment: I don't know the exact reason, but it must have something to do with webpack/vite as `assets` folder is processed by the bundler. If you placed these images in your public directory (which you should), then `requiring` wouldn't be needed and direct string paths would have worked.